# urldecode in objective-c

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm dealing with an urlencoded string in objective-c. Is there a foundation function that actually reverse the urlENCODING?

The string received is like: K%FChlschrank but should be after decoding Kühlschrank

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Apple has depreacted `stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:` 
since iOS9. Please use `stringByRemovingPercentEncoding`.

The new method, Returns a new string made from the receiver by replacing all percent-encoded sequences with the matching UTF-8 characters.

Example:

```
NSString *encodedLink = @"hello%20world";
NSString *decodedUrl = [encodedLink stringByRemovingPercentEncoding];
NSLog (@"%@", decodedUrl);
```

Output:

```
hello world
```

Comment: but this does not convert + symbols with " " spaces

Comment: @veereshkumbar - this is not true, the `encodedLink` variable should be encoded. 

For example `hello world` should be encoded to `hello%20world`. In this case, when you get `hello%20world` as the encodedLink, the `decodedUrl` variable will be `hello world`.

Answer (score 61):

I made a quick category to help resolve this :)

```
@interface NSString (stringByDecodingURLFormat)
- (NSString *)stringByDecodingURLFormat;
@end

@implementation NSString
- (NSString *)stringByDecodingURLFormat
{
    NSString *result = [(NSString *)self stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"+" withString:@" "];
    result = [result stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    return result;
}
@end
```

Once defined, this quickly can handle an encoded string:

```
NSString *decodedString = [myString stringByDecodingURLFormat];
```

Plenty of other ways to implement.

Comment: I believe the  NSString result, should actually be  NSString* result.

Comment: Great. How do you change &amp; into & though? or &rquote; into " . And all their kind?

Comment: I wrote a similar category but ran in to an issue when I tried to decode a string @"abcjhjhdfjhafjakhfjaklfj12346890(*^$#@@@#$%^^     ........", it this method returns nil. It looks like stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding is causing some problems because of "Returns nil if the transformation is not possible (i.e. the percent escapes give a byte sequence not legal in the given encoding). " (from NSURL.h). So just a heads up for those that ran into this issue.

Comment: Good answer, the same issue we got. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 17):

I believe this is what you are looking for:

```
- (NSString *)stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:(NSStringEncoding)encoding
```

Return Value:

A new string made by replacing in the receiver all percent escapes with the matching characters as determined by the given encoding. It returns `nil` if the transformation is not possible, for example, the percent escapes give a byte sequence not legal in encoding.

```
[source: Apple NSString Class Reference]
```

Comment: what encoding should I pass as parameter? tried NSUTF8StringEncoding already

Comment: um, i don't know what encoding that actually is, but there is a long list available in the documentation.

Comment: okay, I was getting response from an NSURLRequest. Following line fixed the issure: NSString* deviceName = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding];

Comment: You should use NSUTF8StringEncoding when you do the URL decoding step, since the encoded bytes are in UTF8 format, if they follow any recent specs (I don't have them to hand).

Comment: You'll also want to replace "+" with " " (space) *before* you do the percent escape replacements.

Comment: Thx for the hint d11wtq. Think is, due to a super crapping front end, that we have to deal with, the string encoding is plattform dependant. Stupid I know!

Answer (score 7):

```
- (NSString *)URLDecode:(NSString *)stringToDecode
{
    NSString *result = [stringToDecode stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"+" withString:@" "];
    result = [result stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    return result;
}
```

That's it

Answer (score 3):

According to [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp), URLs can only be sent over the Internet using the ASCII character set. For me this piece of code worked:

```
NSString *original = @"K%FChlschrank";

NSString *result2 = [original stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

Answer (score -1):

For parmanent solution on iOS 9, use fallowing code

```
NSURL* link = [NSURL URLWithString:[url stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet]]];
```

Comment: Your answer is for encoding the string but we need the one to decode the string.