# Decode URL into JSON

Tags: iphone, ios, json, urldecode

I am getting the following response
           `param=%7B%22paymentMode%22:%22%22,%22transactionId%22:%2231674%22,%22pgRespCode%22:%223%22,%22TxMsg%22:%22Canceled%20by%20user%22,%22authIdCode%22:%22%22,%22currency%22:%22INR%22,%22amount%22:%221.00%22,%22addressStreet1%22:%22Sesame%20street%22,%22addressStreet2%22:%22%22,%22isCOD%22:%22%22,%22loadStatus%22:%22fail%22,%22TxId%22:%22123456%22,%22addressCountry%22:%22India%22,%22firstName%22:%22Ankur%22,%22TxGateway%22:%22%22,%22signature%22:%2245558eb93513aa7a4f2fba24e0ba577b26eb5f40%22,%22addressState%22:%22Pune%22,%22lastName%22:%22Arya%22,%22addressCity%22:%22%22,%22TxRefNo%22:%22CTX1307151506338704178%22,%22loadAmount%22:%221.00%20INR%22,%22pgTxnNo%22:%22CTX1307151506338704178%22,%22TxStatus%22:%22CANCELED%22,%22email%22:%22daredevil.suyash@gmail.com%22,%22issuerRefNo%22:%22%22,%22mobileNo%22:%229900414420%22,%22addressZip%22:%22411045%22%7D`

how can I decode it into the following

```
param={"paymentMode":"","transactionId":"31674","pgRespCode":"3","TxMsg":"Canceled by user","authIdCode":"","currency":"INR","amount":"1.00","addressStreet1":"Sesame street","addressStreet2":"","isCOD":"","loadStatus":"fail","TxId":"123456","addressCountry":"India","firstName":"Ankur","TxGateway":"","signature":"45558eb93513aa7a4f2fba24e0ba577b26eb5f40","addressState":"Pune","lastName":"Arya","addressCity":"","TxRefNo":"CTX1307151506338704178","loadAmount":"1.00 INR","pgTxnNo":"CTX1307151506338704178","TxStatus":"CANCELED","email":"daredevil.suyash@gmail.com","issuerRefNo":"","mobileNo":"9900414420","addressZip":"411045"}
```

Comment: Receiving a response which seems to be URL encoded JSON - is at least extremely unusual and unnecessary. You are sure you didn't get this due to a bug in the web service?

Comment: It might be a bug in web service but the developer told me to decode it. If this is not right I can ask him to give a better response.

Comment: Yes, the most appropriate content-type for JSON data would be `Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8`. You might request this type explicitly through specifying the accept header in your request accordingly:  `Accept: application/json;charset=utf-8`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this method `stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy]`

Taken from this question [urldecode in objective-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4696515/urldecode-in-objective-c)
//

```
NSString *param=@"%7B%22paymentMode%22:%22%22,%22transactionId%22:%2231674%22,%22pgRespCode%22:%223%22,%22TxMsg%22:%22Canceled%20by%20user%22,%22authIdCode%22:%22%22,%22currency%22:%22INR%22,%22amount%22:%221.00%22,%22addressStreet1%22:%22Sesame%20street%22,%22addressStreet2%22:%22%22,%22isCOD%22:%22%22,%22loadStatus%22:%22fail%22,%22TxId%22:%22123456%22,%22addressCountry%22:%22India%22,%22firstName%22:%22Ankur%22,%22TxGateway%22:%22%22,%22signature%22:%2245558eb93513aa7a4f2fba24e0ba577b26eb5f40%22,%22addressState%22:%22Pune%22,%22lastName%22:%22Arya%22,%22addressCity%22:%22%22,%22TxRefNo%22:%22CTX1307151506338704178%22,%22loadAmount%22:%221.00%20INR%22,%22pgTxnNo%22:%22CTX1307151506338704178%22,%22TxStatus%22:%22CANCELED%22,%22email%22:%22daredevil.suyash@gmail.com%22,%22issuerRefNo%22:%22%22,%22mobileNo%22:%229900414420%22,%22addressZip%22:%22411045%22%7D";
    NSString *newParam = [param stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy];
    NSLog(@"%@",newParam);
```

Comment: My only concern with this Yan, is that when you go to compile this, the compiler will likely have a problem with the % symbols in the `param` string. It will try to interpret them as escape characters, and cause a problem. You would need %% instead of %

Comment: Of course the param string is just for example, but just a quick note about it :)

Comment: I ran it in xcode and didn't get any errors.  It interpreted the whole line as string.  The only thing i am not sure about is the encoding parameter.  I just picked one out of two :)  I guess you should use the one that was mentioned in the answer NSUTF8StringEncoding

Comment: NSUTF8StringEncoding would likely work best. But as long as things are coming through consistently, no need to be concerned.

Answer (score 1):

Do string replacement stuff with that to get it into a more readable form.

```
string = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @"%%22" withString:@"\""];
string = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @"%%7B" withString:@"{"];
string = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @"%%7D" withString:@"}"];
```

And so on, until you get it into something you want.

You are basically replacing the unicode representation of the character into the actual readable character

Comment: Thanks MZimmerman6 for the answer but I followed the link that Yan has mentioned in his answer.

Comment: I recommend his anyway, it is much simpler