# URL Decode in Objective-C, converting %7B to { and %22 to "

Tags: objective-c, json, nsstring

How to convert `%7B` to `{` and `%22` to `"` using Objective C and Xcode.

My jsonString is format is : `%7B%22maxTemp%22:%2235%22`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is something wrong with your `NSJSONSerialization`.

Here's a sample converting response data to `JSONObject`:

```
[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[YourResponseData]
                                options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments
                                  error:&error];
```

Here's about your question, using `stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding` will do the trick:

```
NSString *string = [@"%7B%22maxTemp%22:%2235%22" stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

NSLog(@"%@", string);
```

From apples [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios//documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:):

> Return Value A new string made by replacing in the receiver all
>   percent escapes with the matching characters as determined by the
>   given encoding encoding. Returns nil if the transformation is not
>   possible, for example, the percent escapes give a byte sequence not
>   legal in encoding.

Also, take note that this function is deprecated in iOS 9.0 you might want to read about that.

---

Output:

```
{"maxTemp":"35"
```

Comment: @j.Dulu: Welcome bud. Cheers! ;)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to URL decode that string - perhaps the [following post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4696515/urldecode-in-objective-c) may be of use.