# How do decode html data in ios?

Tags: html, ios, objective-c, decoding

I have data in the form :

```
%3Cp%3E%3Cstrong%3Ee-AWB+and+e
```

I have to decode this and display in a Webview/UILabel!

I have tried this - [URL Decoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4696515/urldecode-in-objective-c), but it isn't working for me

Comment: What are you expecting that string to be once decoded?

Comment: make it as a string and replace special characters with relevant characters to make Proper data.

Comment: @AllanPoole i want result in this form - <p><strong>e-AWB and e....

Comment: @AkshayYerneni check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1105169/html-character-decoding-in-objective-c-cocoa-touch

Comment: Try to use the native `NSAttributedString` with `NSHTMLTextDocumentType` attribute.

Comment: @AkshayYerneni Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3423545/objective-c-iphone-percent-encode-a-string it will help to get an idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this -

```
- (NSString *)URLDecode:(NSString *)htmlString
{
    NSString *decodedURL = [htmlString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"+" withString:@" "];
    decodedURL = [decodedURL stringByRemovingPercentEncoding];
    return decodedURL;
}
```

Here you get the output as - `<p><strong>e-AWB and e`

Comment: Glad to help you.

Comment: Umm, could you please help out with one more issue? How do display this decoded data in webview ?

Comment: I was trying the same thing, no content is showing in the webview :/

Comment: I was just trying out your solution. Umm, it still isn't displaying any data in the webview. What's the need of passing the URL - http://website.com ?

Comment: Okay. I've tried, still no go :/ Anyways, thanks for helping in html decoding ! I'll figure something out for data display. I'll update the answer as soon as I get it working

Comment: It worked with setting the baseURL to nil. The array which I had to show was showing empty, I corrected that and everything worked